# Font description in Mono

Tags: fonts, mono, monodevelop

I want to set a label font in mono develop on windows.but i am a beginner on mono and i don't see Font on properties(like visual studio). how to change font description on Mono?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just with code.

```
public static Pango.FontDescription Font (string Family, int Size,Pango.Style Sty=Pango.Style.Normal)
    {
        Pango.FontDescription F=new Pango.FontDescription();
        F.Family=Family;
        F.Size=Size;
        F.Style=Sty;
        return F;
    }
```

and

```
lbl_Inf.ModifyFont(Font("Arial",23));
```